# How to append a list to a list created by a function in Python

Tags: python, list, concatenation

Okay, I have a list that looks like this

```
OldList = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]
```

And I want to run all members of that list through a function called ListMultiply, like so

```
NewList = ListMultiply("/listfile/" + oldList]
```

How do I do this without concatenating string/list? Thanks.

Comment: Wait, what? Please include output in the example and show ListMultiply or at least its documentation (takes X, does Y, returns Z).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NewList = [ListMultiply("/listfile/"+str(e)) for e in OldList]
```

The above will create a new list by adding the string `"/listfile/"` to the string representation of each element and passing the result to `ListMultiply()`.

Comment: Aah. Thanks. I'm sort of new to Python, this worked perfectly.

Comment: I think this is right - but the question is so poorly written it's hard to be sure ;)

Comment: `str(e)`, otherwise it's `TypeError`. Or `'/listfile/{0}'.format(e)`.

Comment: no need for str(e), the numbers were already in strings. Needed them to be for now. Sorry about the poorly written question :(

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate the string/list somewhere("".join or str.format would be better anyway), but I think you look something like:

```
>>> OldList = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]
>>> def f(x):
...     return x*2
... 
>>> OldList = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]
>>> NewList = [f("listfile/" + str(i)) for i in OldList]
>>> NewList
['listfile/1000listfile/1000', 'listfile/2000listfile/2000', 'listfile/3000listfile/3000', 'listfile/4000listfile/4000', 'listfile/5000listfile/5000']
```